# Is it possible to restrict assets in multi region/site specific similarly to how you can restrict entries?

Tags: localization, craft3

Is it possible to assign regions to assets similarly to the way that we restrict entries to a region for multi-region/sites?

Ideally I could specify a path for each region/site as well.

Answer (score 1):

Currently Asset Volumes in Craft 3 are defined on a global basis.  If you would like to see differently, you can create a [feature request](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues) and be sure to include your use-case.

Asset fields have advanced settings where you can relate Assets from a specific site or not in the Control Panel under Assets->Fields->(your Asset field)->Advanced